# Inno Setup how to change the font color or style of label on TInputFileWizardPage

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a input file wizard page where I select a file and proceed with the next page. The code is as follows.

```pascal
[Code]
var
    PageFileSelect: TInputFileWizardPage;

function CreateFileSelectPage(): String;
begin
    PageFileSelect := CreateInputFilePage(PagePreviousPage.ID,
        'Select File',
        'Select File Location',
        'Additional comments...');

    PageFileSelect.Add('Font color or style change required...',
        'test.exe',
        '*.exe');

    PageFileSelect.Values[0] := FileLocation;
end;
```

Is there a way to change the font color or style (bold, italic) for the line *"Font color or style change required..."* in the wizard page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311258/skinned-innosetup-showing-text-instead-of-scrollbar

Comment: Am not using any skin apps currently. I have modified the text color and style in Custom pages. Thought there might be a way to do so in my current page as well.

Comment: I don't even know how to do  that! MAybe @martin-prikryl can help with this.

Comment: `[Code]
var
NewStaticText2: TNewStaticText;
function CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
begin
 { NewStaticText2 }
  NewStaticText2 := TNewStaticText.Create(Page);
  with NewStaticText2 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption :='Font in Bold';
    Width := ScaleX(293);
    Height := ScaleY(62);
    AutoSize := False;
    Font.Color := -16777208;
    Font.Height := ScaleY(-11);
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Font.Style := [fsBold];
    ParentFont := False;
    TabOrder := 1;
    WordWrap := True;
  end;
 end;` @AndrewTruckle

Comment: I see. You can set the properties at design time. Not sure you can do these adjustments to predefined custom pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`TInputFileWizardPage.PromptLabels`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputFileWizardPage) to access the `TNewStaticText` instance that represents the label:

```pascal
PageFileSelect.PromptLabels[0].Font.Color := clRed;
PageFileSelect.PromptLabels[0].Font.Style := [fsBold, fsItalic];
```

[image]