# Change the entire font name of all dialogs (part 2)

Tags: delphi, fonts, inno-setup, font-size, font-style

Based on this post,

[Change the entire font style of all dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076216/change-the-entire-font-style-of-all-dialogs)

How to change the font text of the entire installer in [Graphical Installer](http://www.graphical-installer.com)?

When you create the installer using this tool, it creates two Inno Setup files. One file the main installer file and the other has the code to set the theme. This second file has the extension ".graphics.iss". It has the following code,

```
#define public ButtonNormalColor   "$FFFFFF"
#define public ButtonFocusedColor  "$FFFFFF"
#define public ButtonPressedColor  "$FFFFFF"
#define public ButtonDisabledColor "$FFFFFF"
```

Adding this code,

```
#define public ButtonFont "Times New Roman"
```

does not change the font.

Comment: Simply providing a #define doesn't work unless somewhere there is code that uses that definition. Apparently there is code that uses the button `*Color` definitions, but there is none that looks for a font name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
[Setup]
DefaultDialogFontName=<your font name here e.g. Showcard Gothic>
```

**DefaultDialogFontName** is a directive that works in both Graphical Installer and vanilla Inno Setup.

Please keep in mind, that font used in this directive **must** be present on target machine (it is not compiled automatically into setup). If font is not found, the default (usually Tahoma) will be used.

[image: Custom font]